# Select layout xml files most appropriate, depending on screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I would like to know if You Could select a layaout xml Differently Depending on the size of the phone screen.
I try to  be more clear, I make more layout xml file, and I would like my app handles this statement

```
setContentView (R.layout.main)
```

first verifying on that size of the display is performed, and Therefore You Set the most appropriate layout xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could actually do is the following:

Create a new folder for each desired configuration and name that folder with qualifiers.

If you want your application to have a different **main.xml** layout for different screen sizes you should make the following folders in your project.

```
/res/layout-small
/res/layout-normal
/res/layout-large
/res/layout-xlarge
```

In each of those folders have your different **main.xml** file layout (or whatever resource you want). Android will pick the one it matches with the device is running your application.

You can even add different resources for different configurations for drawables and even for language.

More info: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) page yet?

You can query the size of the device screen, and then select which xml layout you want to use for that size screen...